# How to execute SSIS package from windows form applicaiton VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ssis, etl, dts

My idea is to have 2 projects. BYMacroServices and BYTaskScheduler
BYMacroServices is to store all SSIS packages (.dtsx).
BYTaskScheduler is to write logic to decide when to execute certain package.

## What i have done

I already downloaded and installed SSIS.
[SSIS Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34BGB.png)

I created a reference folder and added a reference which is **Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS**. This dll was obtained from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91

**BYTaskScheduler\Form1.vb**

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnExecutePackage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecutePackage.Click
        Dim packagePath As String = "C:\Projects\BYTaskScheduler\BYMacroServices\Package.dtsx"

        ' Create an instance of the SSIS application
        Dim app As New Application()

        ' Load the package
        Dim package As Package = app.LoadPackage(packagePath, Nothing)

        ' Execute the package
        Dim results As DTSExecResult = package.Execute()

        ' Check execution result
        If results = DTSExecResult.Success Then
            MessageBox.Show("Package executed successfully.")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Package execution failed.")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Error occured**

[Error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvBWA.png)

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=16.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

i tried searching in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL, but could not find the **Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap**. This dll is missing.

SQL Server Integration Services does not running under the SQL Server Services on SQL Server Configuration Manager. It is missing. [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BydE9.png)

Any solution to successfully execute the SSIS package? Thanks in advance